# cannot read properties of undefined // access specific index of array in react js [0]

Tags: arrays, reactjs

[image: this code works]

the code works fine but when I try to access the first index it says "cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')"

[image: this code doesn't work]

this is the response of `console.log("Dataa", this.state.data.videos)`

[image: response]

this is the response of `console.log("Dataa", this.state.data.videos[0])`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are trying to get an index of undefined. Before setting the state to data, the state key 'videos' is undefined. You can try in render:

```
if (this.state.data.videos) {
  console.log('Data', this.state.data.videos[0])
}
```